# Bad redirection through ingress-controllers with custom ports on OpenShift

Tags: nginx, openshift, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, haproxy-ingress

My scheme:

```
Previous traffic path:
-- 80 --> Ingress -- 80 --> Nginx -- 8123 --> Backend
```

I've changed the listening ports in the Nginx container to migrate from k8s to OpenShift.
Now my Nginx works on port 8081 instead of 80.

```
Current traffic path:
-- 80 --> Ingress -- 8081 --> Nginx -- 8123 --> Backend
```

My nginx.conf:

```sh
server {
    listen   8081;

    server_name frontend;
    charset utf8;

    }
    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8123;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    }

***
```

When I open the `https://<My-test-app>/auth` in browser I get the redirect `https://<My-test-app>:8081/auth`.

I've tried to fix this problem on my k8s stand, and I've done it.

These annotations have been very usefull:

```sh
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from : http://<My-test-app>:8081/
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to : https://<My-test-app>/
```

But the OpenShift used an HA-Proxy ingress controller and I couldn't found any annotations like these.

Maybe someone has resolved this problem or known a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this problem on an application level. Adding the line `proxy_redirect http://backend:8123/ http://backend/` helped to solve this problem.

```
server {
    listen   8081;

    server_name frontend;
    charset utf8;

    }
    location /auth {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8123;
        proxy_redirect http://backend:8123/ http://backend/
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    }

***
```